# Display Total Number of Posts per Page without Pagination in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to display a total number of posts for main categories in WordPress instead of displaying all the posts.

How do I go about limiting the total number of posts displayed without pagination?

The following doesn't work:

```
function target_main_category_query_with_conditional_tags( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ( is_category(array( 45, 49 )) ) {

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
            $query->set( 'nopaging', true );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'target_main_category_query_with_conditional_tags' );
```

Comment: You're trying to set both 'posts_per_page' and 'nopaging' at the same time. The 'nopaging' parameter, when set to true, will override 'posts_per_page' and display all posts.

Comment: What's wrong with using pagination? If you want to display the total post count but only display some of the posts you'll need two queries. One to get the count and another to get the actual posts using an order by and limit (max rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code manipulates the category page.

```
<?php
function target_main_category_query_atakanau( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() && $query->get_queried_object()->parent == 0 ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true );
        // Adds HTML to the category description:
        add_filter( 'category_description', 'add_content_to_category_description_atakanau', 10, 2);
    }
}
function add_content_to_category_description_atakanau( $description , $category_id) {
    $total_post_count = total_posts_of_category_atakanau($category_id);
    $new_description = $description . '<p>This category contains a total of '.$total_post_count.' posts.</p>';
    return $new_description;
}
function total_posts_of_category_atakanau($category_id) {
    $total_post_count = 0;

    $subcategories = get_categories( array(
        'child_of' => $category_id,
    ) );

    foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {
        $total_post_count += $subcategory->count;
    }

    // Add the post count of the given category itself
    $main_category = get_category( $category_id );
    $total_post_count += $main_category->count;

    return $total_post_count;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'target_main_category_query_atakanau' );
```

Conditions:

`! is_admin()` : A visitor without the admin role

`$query->is_category()`: Category page

`$query->get_queried_object()->parent == 0`: The parent category

Note: as @Karl Hill said, `nopaging` parameter overrides `posts_per_page`, do not use it.